# Array.length is 3 but logs an "empty" array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, asynchronous, twitch

**Results I hope to log**: [ 'freecodecamp' , 'twitchtv' ,  'exercise' ]

I've read a bunch of post regarding [Asynchronous situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260524/array-length-is-zero-but-the-array-has-elements-in-it) which explains why I'm getting these "empty [ ]" on the Console:   
 "empty" meaning it appears like this:[ ],  
 rathan than this : [ 'freecodecamp' , 'twitchtv' ,  'exercise' ].

**What I'm getting** so far : if ***console.log(online_streamer)*** is placed as follow scenarios:

A. (Within getJSON callback) --- logs: undefined, then a couple lines of empty [ ] before printing the final "usable" array with 3 items(gamers names) in it.

B. (Outside forLoop) --- logs: 1 [ ] array with 3-items to show ONLY if I press the arrow down button. Again, [(Async situation.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260524/array-length-is-zero-but-the-array-has-elements-in-it)

**My Question :** 
Did I misplace the consoe.log or do I need some complete different function to print a usable array like: [ 'item1' , 'item2' , 'item3' ] like the last iteration of scenario **A.)** ? Thanks guys.

```
function getOnlineGamers(){
    var online_gamers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<gamers.length; i++){
        //(gamers is a defined array with 11names of 11gamers.)

        $.getJSON(url+"streams/"+ gamers[i]+cid).done(function(data){
            if(data.stream === null){
            }else {
                var name= data.stream.channel.name;
                online_gamers.push(name);
            }
            console.log(online_gamers);  // <--- A 
        });
    };
    console.log(online_gamers); //<--- B 
};

console.log(getOnlineGamers())
```

Comment: getOnlineGamers() doesn't return anything, so logging it won't log anything useful. You need to use proper "async return" techniques.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The first empty array is from `B`, then an `undefined` from `console.log(getOnlineGamers())`, *then* `A` may be logging something.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait for each resolution, 
then you can work with the resulting array.

```js
function getOnlineGamers(gamers, cid) {

  return Promise
    .all(gamers.map(function(game) {
       return $
        .getJSON(url + "streams/" + game + cid)
        .then(function(data) {

          return data.stream && data.stream.channel.name;
        })
      ;
    }))
  ;
}    


getOnlineGamers([123, 321, 231], 'foobaz')
  .then(function(names) {

    console.log('names', names);
  })
;
```