# NodeList has 3 elements but behaves like it has 2 elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, children

I'm having the weirdest output where the debugger says the Node has 2 children when it has 3. Even the in the image I post here I see some incongruences, where it says the `length` of the object is 3 but for some reason, it prints that the `length` is 2.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this behaviour ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Cause `NodeList(2)` is logged, and the rest gets composed by the console when you click on it, thats "live", so the list changed inbetween.

Comment: See the light blue box that has `i` in it on the right of `NodeList (2)`? [**Hover it**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6WTT.jpg).

Comment: [**Simillar problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42260524/6647153)

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks !

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thank you

Comment: You're calling this a "bug". In what way is this console behavior impacting your application code such that it causes a bug?

Comment: @CrazyTrain As I learned now, it's not a bug. In the beggining I didn't know that. Already edited the question

Comment: Oh, I see. You thought the console had a bug. Yeah, consoles often reevaluate reference types, but generally not primitives or certain labels. Ultimately, it's up to them how their output behaves; there's no standard that describes a required behavior.

Comment: @CrazyTrain thanks good to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what is likely happening:

When you log the NodeList to the console it has 2 elements, but in the moment you expand the preview, it has 3 elements. The same effect can be observed, when you add an item to an array after a certain timeout:

[image]

`console.log()` changes the view live, so whenever the item changes you can see it when expanding it