# Storing and Getting array of objects in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am storing each response entity in object then pushing them in array
where case 1 is working while case 2 is not.

Case 1 dummy data from external JSON file:

```
 const {addEvent} = this.props
         var airportList= FlightInfo.Airport; //FlightInfo carries data in JSON 
                                              //file
        var newEvents=[];

        for(var rootKey in airportList){
          if(rootKey===airportValueSelected)
           { 

               airportList[rootKey].forEach(element => {


                   if(element.flight_no===flightValue){

                     for(var m=0;m<element.Events.length;m++){
                    var singleEvent={
                    event_name:'',
                    date_time:'',
                    status:'',
                    }

                      singleEvent.event_name=element.Events[m].event_name;
                      singleEvent.date_time=element.Events[m].date_time;
                      singleEvent.status=element.Events[m].status;
                      newEvents.push(singleEvent);
                    }

                    for(var s=0;s<element.Alerts.length;s++){

                      newAlerts.push(element.Alerts[s]["Alert"+(s+1)]);

                    }

                   }

               });
               addEvent(newEvents);
```

**The console result from Case 2:**
[image: Console result of **newEvents** from Case 1]

Above response if you look closely I am getting [{...}]

Now Case 2 from Server response

```
axios.get('http://localhost:6020/fetchData?name='+data1+'&flight_no='+data2+'&date='+data3)

               .then(res=>{
               console.log(res);
               console.log(res.data.resultSet);
               if(res.data.error==null || res.data.error===""){
                 res.data.resultSet.forEach(element => {
                   var singleEvent={
                     completionIntent:'',
                     Name:'',
                     flightno:'',
                     date:'',
                     audioFileName:'',
                     status:'',
                   };

                   singleEvent.airportName=element.airportName;
                   singleEvent.completionIntent=element.completionIntent;
                   singleEvent.audioFileName=element.audioFileName;
                   singleEvent.flightno=element.flightno;
                   singleEvent.departureDate=element.departureDate;
                   singleEvent.status='On-time';
                   newEvents.push(singleEvent);
                 });

               }
           }).catch((e)=>console.log("Can’t access"+e));
           console.log(newEvents);
           addEvent(newEvents);
```

**The console result from Case 2:**

[image: console result **newEvents** from case 2]

Now in second case when I pass these **newEvents** to B(main) component and then to C component it becomes empty when I try to get value `{this.props.events}`

**B Component:**

```
export default class userLogin extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            events:[],
        };

      }

      addEvent = newEvent => this.setState({
        events: newEvent
      });

  render(){
        const {events} = this.state

        return(

                    <SearchFlight events={events} alerts={alerts} addAlert={this.addAlert} addEvent={this.addEvent} />

                    <Events events={events}/>

        );

    }
```

**UPDATE: ADD EVENT COMPONENT**

```
render(){
       console.log("this event:"+this.props.events);
        return(
            <div style={{display:'block',}}>
            <div className="row" >

            {this.props.events.map((event) =>
               (
                <div className="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" key={event.completionIntent}  >
               <Card style={{minWidth : '275px', backgroundColor:'#F5F5F5', marginBottom:'10px', marginRight:'2px',}}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography style={{fontSize:'14px',}} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                        <p style={{fontSize:'20px',width:'78px', marginBottom:'0px',float:'right',}} >{event.status}</p>
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2" style={{fontWeight:'bold',}}>
                         {event.airportName.toUpperCase()}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography style={{marginBottom:'12px'}} color="textSecondary">
                        Event
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography component="p" style={{color: event.status==='On-time'?'#33691E':event.status==='Delayed'?'#D50000':'grey', fontSize: '12px',}}>
                        {event.departureDate}
                        <br />
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small">Download Audio {event.audioFileName}</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
                </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**Problem:** Getting empty props events when passing to Events component. Case 1 is working fine but I didn't change anything except add few more objects and it stops working

Comment: In which component you are calling the API and on which life cycle method you are  calling can you please paste the code for thes

Comment: @HarishSoni but I am not using lifecycle methods to defined or set newEvents it is declared inside `handleSubmit` method and case 1 and case 2 are the part of code from `handleSubmit`

Comment: Can you please create a demo on http://codesandbox.com ?

Comment: @HarishSoni [{..}] result after adding in case 1 and [] result after adding in case 2....if I check the length in case 2 it's zero but if there is no data then what's I am receiving look in the image

Comment: @HarishSoni see method handle submit I have added the whole code for that component since it's a lot of code therefore look that particular method

Comment: @HarishSoni have you checked that?

Comment: Can you post the code of your `Events` Component

Comment: @in the above link? sandbox?

Comment: No on the question

Comment: @HarishSoni added event component at the last

Comment: You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` in your `Events` Component and then map your props to the state;

Comment: but in case 1 it worked without any issue since in B component you can see I am passing events as prop value and printing {this.props.events} but nothing I am getting. Can you tell me by looking at the image what [] and [{...}] make a difference even I did the same thing almost and one has length zero while other has a length and if it has zero length then where is that data lying which is showing in case 2 image????????

Comment: @HarishSoni My question is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260524/array-length-is-zero-but-the-array-has-elements-in-it with my problem context

Comment: When you console.log something it prints the initial value. but it continuously checks for the modified value of the same. now when you expand the same you get the elements in it. This is the default behavior of chrome.

Comment: @HarishSoni what I am saying is I did exactly same in case 1 but it is working.....and I am not getting anything in case 2 in prop value of events

Comment: @HarishSoni I resolved it by placing the `addEvent(newEvents)` method inside the forEach loop. I don't know the working but it did the work for me