# Resolving Elements in Array when Array Length is 0 (MongoDB, React, Axios)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I am writing an application that makes a `GET` request through axios to a server I have written. Here is the server code that I have written that may be relevant to the issue.

```
app.get("/getScheduledTimes/:day/:stationId", (req, res) => {
  const {stationId, day} = req.params;
  db.collection(`${day}-schedules`).find({
    stationInfo: {$exists: true}
  }).toArray((error, result) =>{
    if(error) {
      console.log('Schedule Database Error: ', error)
    }
    let scheduledTimes;
    for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      if(result[i].stationInfo[stationId]){
        scheduledTimes = result[i].stationInfo[stationId]
        break;
      }
    }
    scheduledTimes = sortTimeArray(scheduledTimes);
    res.json({
      scheduledTimes: scheduledTimes,
      success: true,
    })
  })
})
```

What sortTimeArray does is basically sorts the array of objects by date. When I look at what it was sending, res.data.scheduledTimes would be an array of objects, which I expected.

When I make the request from the front end though, `originTimeTable` which makes one of the calls returns an array of length 0 with elements in it. However, `departTimeTable` returns the array as I expected.

Here is the client-side code:

```
getTimes = async () => {
    // Make API calls to get the timetables for the selected stations
    const {originStationId, destinationStationId} = this.state;
    const responseOrigin = await axios(`http://localhost:3002/getScheduledTimes/weekday/${originStationId}`)
    const originTimeTable = responseOrigin.data.scheduledTimes;
    const responseDestination = await axios(`http://localhost:3002/getScheduledTimes/weekday/${destinationStationId}`)
    const departTimeTable = responseDestination.data.scheduledTimes;
    await this.setState({
      originTimes: originTimeTable,
      destinationTimes: departTimeTable,
    })
  }
```

The result when I console.log `originTimetable` is:

```
originTimetable:  
(28) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260524/array-length-is-zero-but-the-array-has-elements-in-it) answer and I understand that `originTimetable` array hasn't been resolved. I'm wondering how I can get the elements array to resolve to the array of objects like I expected.

The goal is that I would use `originTimeTable` and `departTimeTable` to then transform them into one array. Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was able to manage to figure it out after some trial and error. This involves using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`. It seems that the key is to use `JSON.stringify` to resolve each of those promises and then use `JSON.parse` to grab the values.

```
const originTimeTable = responseOrigin.data.scheduledTimes.map(
   time => JSON.stringify(time)
);
const departTimeTable = responseDestination.data.scheduledTimes.map(
   time => JSON.stringify(time)
);
this.setState({
   originTimes: originTimeTable,
   destinationTimes: departTimeTable,
})
```

This way, when I actually need it, I can just use `JSON.parse` like so:

```
let {originTimes, destinationTimes} = this.state;
originTimes = originTimes.map(time => JSON.parse(time))
destinationTimes = destinationTimes.map(time => JSON.parse(time))
```

Hopefully this will help someone who has run into this issue!