# array cannot read property of undefined Jupyter Notebook execute.CodeCell

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to get a specific value 'ename' from Juputer Notebook on event of:

```
events.on('execute.CodeCell', function(evt, data) {
    var outputs = data.cell.output_area.outputs; //this works
    console.log(outputs[0].ename) //this does not work
}
```

The above code does not give the required result. While, if I check the same in the Browser, it shows the required result

[image: Required result]

The type of data in the screenshot is an Array. I am not sure why does it not work.
It throws this error:

[image: error]

Please let me know what is wrong in my code or am I missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my own question which will do the trick. It is not actually a solution but it works for me.
Referring to @[ibrahim mahrir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9867451/ibrahim-mahrir) answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260582/5877370), as the code runs from a file that is locally stored, it take time to read. So I need to add a wait time for it.

```
events.on('execute.CodeCell', function(evt, data) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var outputs = data.cell.output_area.outputs;
    console.log(outputs[0].ename)
  }, 1000);
}
```