# Type Error when destructuring elements In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Problem

After I query my objects from GraphQl server, on console logging `data` I get my objects in the console but when I destructure it in a way `data: { getPosts : posts }` it returns a type error and when I try to map over `data` only it returns `data.map is not a function`

### The Code

```
const {loading, data: {getPosts: posts} } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS); // Here is the error

return(
             {loading ? (
                   <h1>Loading...</h1>
               ) : (
                   posts && posts.map(post => (
                       <Grid.Column key={post.id}> 
                           <PostCard post={post} />
                       </Grid.Column>
                    ))
               )}
)
```

### The TypeError

[image: TypeError]

### The data on console.log(data)

[image: Object Error]

Comment: try data.getPosts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/42260524/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of destructuring is not gonna work, because at the time when it happens `data` is still undefined. So you'll need to wait for it to load.

```
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS);

  return loading ? (
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  ) : (
    data.getPosts.map((post) => (
      <Grid.Column key={post.id}>
        <PostCard post={post} />
      </Grid.Column>
    ))
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the async request for the data to be ready so that it can be destructured.